# How to pass data from activity to service while starting service?

Tags: android, android-service

I am creating an application in android.

How to pass an object of ArrayList to service while starting service and access in service???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can put it using intent.putExtra() method and in service you can get array using getParcelableArray method in service onStart() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Override onStart Method in your service.OnStart method you can get intent of Activity. 
If you want to pass ArrayList from activity to service,you can convert your arraylist to array.

In you Activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ServicesActivity.this,FileManagerRequest.class);         
Bundle b=new Bundle()
b.putStringArray("Array", your_array)
intent.putExtras(b);
startService(intent);
```

in you service

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid){
    super.onStart(intent, startid);
    Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
    String[] Array = b.getStringArray("Array");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. If service is local, then you can bind to it and just call methods directly
2. If service is remote, than you can use [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to pass some data.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got answer , its work for me, Just Try it.

1) while sending object likes `ArrayList<String> names` from Activity send to this way example. `names.add("kdblue");`

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(CuurentActivity.this, UploadService.class);
startIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("data",names);
startService(startIntent);
```

2) Now receiving this `ArrayList<String>` object from service

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       ArrayList<String> transferData = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("data");
      return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Note: `transferData` object contains all `ArrayList<String> names` properties .

Answer (score -1):

/*****in your activity******/

```
startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("id", id);
            Intent in=new Intent(create.this,myservice.class);

            in.putExtras(b);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startService(in);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

/*******in your service***********/

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
// stopped, so return sticky.
       super.onStart(intent, startId);
     id=intent.getExtras();
     value=id.getString("id");

Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started "+value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```